# MSBuild ignores p-Switch when publishing database

Tags: msbuild, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

I've created a publish profile via SSDT in VS 2015 targetting a SQL Azure V12 server and now I want to publish the database using the console. I'm using the following command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe  
    /t:Publish 
    /p:TargetDatabaseName=NEWDBNAME        
    /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="PublishProfiles\test.publish.xml" 
    "{PATH_TO_MY_SSDT\{PROJECTNAME}.sqlproj"
```

My profile looks like this (curly braces are just placeholders for real values here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>DBNAME</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>Data.Database.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>True</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <CreateNewDatabase>True</CreateNewDatabase>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source={SERVER};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={USER};Password={PW};Pooling=False</TargetConnectionString>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <SqlCmdVariable Include="BaseData">
      <Value>1</Value>
    </SqlCmdVariable>
    <SqlCmdVariable Include="SampleData">
      <Value>1</Value>
    </SqlCmdVariable>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This creates a database "DBNAME" everytime instead of replacing the property `TargetDatabaseName` with the value "NEWDBNAME". Everything else is working fine.

Why will msbuild leave the property unchanged?

**Edit:**

I tested a little bit around and tried the following (after Christian K.s comment):

Test 1: Adding diag

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe  
    /t:Publish 
    /p:TargetDatabaseName=NEWDBNAME        
    /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="PublishProfiles\test.publish.xml" 
    "{PATH_TO_MY_SSDT\{PROJECTNAME}.sqlproj" 
    /v:diag 
    /fl
```

There is a section in the output showing the parameters. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Normal parameter output]

Test 2: Changing UpdateDatabase for testing purpose

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe  
    /t:Publish 
    /p:TargetDatabaseName=NEWDBNAME        
    /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="PublishProfiles\test.publish.xml" 
    /p:UpdateDatabase=false 
    "{PATH_TO_MY_SSDT\{PROJECTNAME}.sqlproj" 
    /v:diag 
    /fl
```

[image: UpdateDatabase was changed the correct way]

As you can see, `UpdateDatabase` was changed correctly and `TargetDatabaseName` does not appear in the list of properties.

Comment: Try invoking `msbuild.exe` with the options `/v:diag` and `/fl`. Then inspect the created `msbuild.log` file in the current directory and see how the value of `TargetDatabaseName` is set.

Comment: @Christian.K I checked the msbuild.log but "TargetDatabaseName" does not appear in it at all.

Comment: It looks like `TargetDatabaseName` from the XML file is overriding the parameter, so can't you just change the XML?

Comment: Yes I can somehow (MSBuild + XML-File-Manipulation). But the purpose of the /p-Parameter is to override the XML-File-Parameters and this works with the UpdateDatabase-Property as you can see in my last screenshot. If I use some custom override it'll be a mess to automate this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I just set `CreateNewDatabase` in my publish-profile to `false` and it worked.

**Edit**: It only works one time because after that the process is simply skipped because the database already exists. The solution now is to edit the publish.xml before I execute it via code as Kris suggested in his comment.

This is another sample for the incompatibility between SQL Server and SQL Azure which is annoying in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

It is really much simpler just to have an exec task call sqlpackage.exe - I check the sqlpackage folder MSSQL\VER\DAC\bin into my solution so I can use relative paths from the build folder and you can deploy from any server with or without SQL on.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But this does not answer the question. SSDT with MSBuild works fine for me except for one property. I got it working some time ago in another project :-(.